# how to configure jenkins email notifications with microsoft exchange

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to use microsoft exchange server for email notifications in jenkins?

I have provided exchnage server name as smtp server, authentication details, selected ssl and added below argument to the command line 
-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

but still getting the error javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host.